# eclipse Project Explorer preference

Tags: eclipse

My Project Explorer does not show the true name of the file (on the right side in the image), I want it to look like the left side of the image.  I can't find the preference to fix this, please help!

[screen shot of a correct/incorrect project explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3bQI.png)

Comment: That depends on which kind of project (which is not visible on your cropped screenshot) and can be configured in the view menu (the three dots) _Filters and Customization_.

Comment: it's an AEM root folder. Java?  I guess???  The other screenshot (the one I wish to emulate) is a colleague, doing the same work.  She sent me a screen shot of her tree and I was shocked it looked that way, I want mine to be the same but I can't find a setting to change.

Comment: The settings you searching for is in the _Project Explorer_ view menu (the three dots) _Filters and Customization_.